# How to see predictors of each models made by Recursive Feature Elimination (RFE)?

Tags: r, r-caret, rfe

I have used RFE (Recursive Feature Elimination) method to find the best model out of 39 variables. I used the following codes:

```r
set.seed(10)
ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = caretFuncs, method = "repeatedcv",repeats = 5,number= 5,allowParallel = TRUE)

RF_39 <- rfe(X, Y,sizes = c(1:39),method ='rf',rfeControl = ctrl,tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry=6))
```

The best model is made using 36 variables.
If I want to see those 36 variables I can use
`predictors(RF_39)` or `RF_39$optVariable` functions.

However, I need to see the variables used for making the other models rather than the best model.
For example, what are the variables used for making model number 12?
How can I see the variables of a specific model made by RFE method?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean `predictors(model12)`?

Comment: Yes, I do. What variables were used to make model12?

Comment: There is no such object called model12.

Comment: I used 'RF_39$optVariable[1:12]'